# SwiftUI - Animations triggered inside a View that's in a list doesn't animate the list as well

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `List` that's displaying two `Views` of the same type. When you tap on one of the views, they change their height with an animation.

However, the `List` those views are embedded in doesn't animate which results in an ugly glitch because the height of the `List` row changes instantly, while the actual view inside that row is animated:

[image]

How can I make the `List` animate as well? I tried addinga `.animation` modifier to it but that doesn't do anything.

I also don't want to move the `tapGesture` out of the view. The view should be self-contained and not rely on some other view to control it (I think that's what MVVM is about)

thanks!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SubView: View {
    @State var change: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: change ? 300 : 200)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    self.change.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Test: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            SubView()
            SubView()
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you make any progress on this? I'm having exactly the same thing.

Comment: I haven't really had time since then, unfortunately. Might be a bug in `swiftUI`

Comment: @MichaelForrest, see my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is just to make height animatable continuously, by providing explicit animatable modifier for this.

Here is working approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

Implementation of simple helper modifier

```
struct AnimatingCellHeight: AnimatableModifier {
    var height: CGFloat = 0

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { height }
        set { height = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.frame(height: height)
    }
}
```

Modified using view (other parts unchanged)

```
struct SubView: View {
    @State var change: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200)
            .modifier(AnimatingCellHeight(height: change ? 300 : 200))
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    self.change.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, is it possible to automatically determine the cell height? I can’t figure out how you would do this

Comment: @Quantm perhaps you can try and get the cell height using the GeometryReader

Comment: Or use nil, that should set it to default

Comment: I fixed a glitchy `Image` animation in a subview by modifying the `body` of the modifier to round the `height` like this: `content.frame(height: height.rounded())`

Comment: I have a similar problem with elements in a VStack inside a List.  But I don't have any specific frame height to work with.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418666/swiftui-list-animations-are-not-smooth-when-adding-elements-to-a-vstack-in-a-lis/76418792?noredirect=1#comment134751255_76418792