# Alignment of a view within a list row

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the following list, inside each row of the list there is a view which is a colorful rectangle and a text inside (it's the background of the text in the shape of rectangle).

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ListRow: View {
    
    var name:String
    
    var factor : CGFloat

    
    var fillColor:Color
    
    
    var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(self.name)
       .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: self.factor * 
         geometry.size.height)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 
                     5).fill(self.fillColor)).foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                
          }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to control the positioning of the rectangle within the lists row height. Each rectangle have it's height, the problem is that regardless of it's height the rectangle always appear in the center of the list row . I have tried to use `alignment:.top` inside the VStack of listRow or the frame() of text, but there is no effect..

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    

    var range = 1...12
    
    var body: some View {
        

            List(self.range,id:\.self){
                    num in

                ListRow(name: "Some Name", factor:  CGFloat(1.5),fillColor:Color(.pink)).padding()
            }
             
    }
```

}

How can I make the internal view appear from the top of the list row ?

Comment: [Dynamic row height in a SwiftUI form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62482773/12299030) should be helpful.