Conditionally show/hide contents of a ForEach loop with animation
I'm building out a custom approach to handling DisclosureGroups due to limitations I'm experiencing with the DisclosureGroupStyle path currently available. I've got it how I want from a visual and functional perspective with one exception - animation of the contents appearing/disappearing.
I built a sample project to demonstrate a simplified version of the problem.
struct SectionView: View {
    let title: String
    let data: [String]
    
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Text(data.count.description)
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Label("expand", systemImage: "chevron.down")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 0 : -90))
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2), value: isExpanded)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Divider()
            VStack {
                if isExpanded {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let data: [String: [String]] = [
        "Section A": ["Item A.1", "Item A.2", "Item A.3", "Item A.4", "Item A.5" ],
        "Section B": ["Item B.1", "Item B.2"],
        "Section C": ["Item C.1", "Item C.2", "Item C.3", "Item C.4"]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(Array(data.keys).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }), id: \.self) { key in
                        SectionView(title: key, data: data[key]!)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .listStyle(.inset)
                .navigationTitle("Example Project")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


When I press the toggle button, the contents disappear immediately because of the conditional check I've wrapped the ForEach within. Is there a way to animate the contents of the ForEach loop moving upwards towards the Divider and disappearing?
I've tried the following at the bottom of the VStack but it seems to not realize that the contents are disappearing so it doesn't animate.
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: isExpanded)
Divider()
VStack {
    if isExpanded {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: isExpanded)

Any advice on this would be awesome - thanks!

Please try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873883/14015376

It is the List that is crippling the animations. See Broken animation when using custom DisclosureGroup in a SwiftUI List for a possible workaround.

I don't need this to be in a list, I can just use a scroll view for what I'm doing. Is there a cleaner way of handling this if it was just in a scroll view?

I solved for this with a ScrollView and using withAnimation. I posted my solution as an answer

I was able to get something that looked good enough for my particular use-case.
The first change I made was to apply an opacity transition to the Text views being added via the ForEach loop.
if isExpanded {
    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .transition(AnyTransition.opacity)
            .opacity(isExpanded ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    }
}

Next, I wrapped the isExpanded toggle into a call to withAnimation
Button {
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.1)) {
        self.isExpanded.toggle()
    }
} 

Finally, after the comments indicating the List view has issues with animations, I moved my content out of the List and into a ScrollView. For the needs I had, a ScrollView was sufficient.

Now I have a clean animation as the section is collapsed and expanded. The following is the full code.
struct SectionView: View {
    let title: String
    let data: [String]
    
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Text(data.count.description)
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                Spacer()
Button {
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.1)) {
        self.isExpanded.toggle()
    }
} label: {
                    Label("expand", systemImage: "chevron.down")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 0 : -90))
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isExpanded)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Divider()
            VStack {
if isExpanded {
    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .transition(AnyTransition.opacity)
            .opacity(isExpanded ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    }
}
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let data: [String: [String]] = [
        "Section A": ["Item A.1", "Item A.2", "Item A.3", "Item A.4", "Item A.5" ],
        "Section B": ["Item B.1", "Item B.2"],
        "Section C": ["Item C.1", "Item C.2", "Item C.3", "Item C.4"]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(Array(data.keys).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }), id: \.self) { key in
                        SectionView(title: key, data: data[key]!)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .listStyle(.inset)
                .navigationTitle("Example Project")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Thanks for self-answering with the solution you found. (voted.) I'm still learning SwiftUI animation.
